# AsyncTask has weird delay on start up of application

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsynTask implementation that when I start the app from the device the app has a delay. This delay is never present on the first run, but always on the runs following the first, so if I kill the app and come back to it in say 6 minutes it will start the connection and never finish it.

Here is my AsyncTask:

```
private class MakeConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {

    Context context;
    ProgressDialog myDialog;

    public MakeConnection(Context conetext)
    {
        this.context = conetext;
        myDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for(String url : urls)
        {
            try
            {
                URL theUrl = new URL(url);
                URLConnection ucon = theUrl.openConnection();
                ucon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                int current = 0;
                while(((current = bis.read()) != -1) && !isCancelled())
                {
                    baf.append((byte)current);
                }
                response = new String(baf.toByteArray());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                response = e.getMessage();
            }

        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            myDialog.dismiss();
            success(result);
        }catch(JSONException e)
        {
            data = e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                context,
                "Please wait...",
                "Loading the data",
                true,
                true,
                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        MakeConnection.this.cancel(true);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

And then in my onCreate()

```
task = new MakeConnection(this);
task.execute(new String[] {url});
```

I cant understand why this would be happening?

EDIT:

When the app launches the first time it works nicely, but when I re open the app at a later stage the first connection seen above does the following:

- It Starts the progress dialog and then I don't know if it actually makes the connection,              because all I see is the progress dialog that never goes away, in other words it never finishes the connection, because if the connection completed the progress dialog would complete

Comment: Can you re-word or explain more about what is delayed or what connection isn't finishing. Did you put some logging code in "doInBackground" to see when it starts and finishes?

Comment: Ok, well first, you could insert some logging code to see what's actually going on. Second, I still don't know what you mean by "when I re open the app at a later stage". Was the Activity onDestroy method called? Was onCreate actually called a second time? Did you exit to the Home screen then re-launch? Try doing a Force stop on the app in-between runs and see if you get a different result.

Comment: I found the problem was with the web server, so I did a time out force refresh with a timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was that the problem lies with the server getting the request, what I did was add a timer to refresh the connection if it took to long.